# WordPress show image if post has certain story tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently trying to implement a feature to my WordPress site, currently i am using a custom theme with a custom post type called stories.

The way i have it set up so far is when a story is posted in a certain category i show an image on it say for instance its in the uk category it has a UK Flag, and if its in the USA it has a US Flag,

I would like to also show an image say for instance it has a tag of Android i would like to show an image of the android logo.

this is my site so you can see what i am doing - kwikfreebies.com

Here is the code i have been working on and the tag code as well

```html
<span>

<?php

     $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'story_category' );

foreach($terms as $current_term){
    if (  $current_term->slug == "usa-freebies" || $current_term->slug == "free-community-help" || $current_term->slug == "birthday-freebies" ) :?>
     <img class="country" width="30" src="http://kwikfreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/United-States-Flag-icon.png">

    <?php elseif ( $current_term->slug == "uk-freebies" ) : ?>
     <img class="country" width="30" src="http://kwikfreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/United-Kingdom-flag-icon.png">

<?php elseif ( $current_term->story_tags == "apps" ) : ?>
     <img class="country" width="30" src="http://kwikfreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/United-Kingdom-flag-icon.png">

     <?php elseif ( $current_term->term_taxonomy_id == "698" || $current_term->slug == "daily-deals" ) :?>
     <img class="country" width="30" src="http://kwikfreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/keyboard_layout.png">
    <?php endif; }?></span>
```

And here is the coding to show the Tags

```html
     <?php
          $story_tag_terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(),  'story_tag' );
    if ( ! empty( $story_tag_terms ) ) {
     if ( ! is_wp_error( $story_tag_terms ) ) {
       echo '<span><i class="icon icon-tags"></i> '. esc_html__( 'Tags : ', 'upvote-plugin' ) .'</span>';
       foreach( $story_tag_terms as $term ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term->slug, 'story_tag' ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a>'; 
       }
     }
    } else {
     the_tags( '<span><i class="icon icon-tags"></i> '. esc_html__( 'Tags : ', 'upvote-plugin' ) .'</span>', ',&nbsp;', '' );
    }

    // page view counter
    upvote_set_post_views(get_the_ID());
          ?>
```

Comment: you can try to name the images like the tag slug: e.g. tag slug is android then you can link an android.png and show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked it out many thanks for help, i have found that i was using the term story_category for the first statement, so i have written a new statement out for story tags

```html
<?php 

$story_tag_terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(),  'story_tag' );

foreach( $story_tag_terms as $term ) {
 if (  $term->slug == "apps" ) :?>
<img class="country" width="30" src="http://kwikfreebies.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/United-Kingdom-flag-icon.png">


<?php endif; }?>
```